# What specific vegetables, variables, or other things can I add to food to make it less greasy

Tags: oil, fish, deep-frying

My mother is bringing home Kevins Seafood. If u don't know what it is know that its fried fish thats very, very greasy. I was thinking about making some potato salad to go with the fish. I could  even make something with tomatoes to cut through that greasyness. Maybe even a salad or just some stir fried vegetables. But I need a common opinion. I do not want to eat all that oil. Thanks in advance :D

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is no way to actually reduce the oil content (though, in reality, it is probably less than you think), but often acidic accompaniments are served with high fat or rich foods, to cut the perception of "greasiness" and clean the palate.  Tomatoes are a good idea, as is a salad, especially with a vinegar based dressing.  I would say you are on the right track. As for not wanting to "eat that much oil", all you can do is eat less or choose an alternate for your main course.

Comment: Just to add a bit to your great answer: at least in my country it's common to add lemon to greasy foods to 'reduce the grease' (popular belief, not scientifically based). It's also common to add lemon to fish and seafood (there's actually a 'meme fight' with pro lemoners and anti lemoners on food). So I guess that would also work, if the taste is pleasant for OP. And an example of greasy fish/sea food: [calamares a la romana](https://www.hogarmania.com/archivos/202206/karl6992-calamares-romana-xl-1280x720x80xX.jpg).